# Capital Y vs small y

Tags: algorithms, accept-reject

I want to use the acceptance-rejection method to generate a sample from the following target probability density function:
$$f\left(x\right)=1.25x^4+2x^3+0.25,\:0<x<1$$

Let the trial probability density function be
$$g\left(x\right)\:=\:1,\:0<x<1$$

```r
n <- 100000
k <- 0      #counter for accepted
j <- 0      #iterations
x <- numeric(n)

while (k < n) 
{
  u <- runif(1)
  j <- j + 1
  y <- runif(1)  #random variate from g
  if (u<((1.25*(y^4)+2*(y^3)+0.25)/3.5)) {
    #we accept y
    k <- k + 1
    x[k] <- y}
}
j
hist(x, prob = TRUE, main = bquote(f(x)==1.25*(x^4) + 2*(x^3) + 
       0.25)) #density histogram of sample
curve(1.25*(x^4)+2*(x^3)+0.25,xlim=c(0,1),add=T,col="blue")
```

The samples match with the theoretical graph so I think my method is ok. I'm just confused about the question on the second page: "If the first uniform in the accept-rejection algorithm in was U = 0.5 and the first candidate draw was Y = 0.75. Would you accept or reject this candidate?"

We would accept right? Since U < 0.75?

Comment: Please explain your title.  As far as answering the question goes, why not manually set `u` and `y` in your loop to the values in the question and see what happens?

Comment: @whuber but thats what I'm confused about. Do they mean (u<((1.25*(0.75^4)+2*(0.75^3)+0.25)/3.5)) or (u<0.75)?

Comment: You are told $U=0.5$ and $Y=0.75.$  What does the algorithm do in that case?

Comment: @whuber we accept y and add it to our sample?

Comment: Maybe you should step through your code a few times to understand what it's doing: that would be instructive.

Comment: @whuber Ohhh. I guess its (if 0.5 < 0.42255) which is false, so we reject y and loop